# Test webClient in microservices app using wiremock

Tags: spring-boot, testing, spring-cloud, wiremock

`I am not able to test a controller whose service references another microservice, microservices run in eureka server and access to them is provided by api-gateway, application running normally, works fine but wiremock in tests "does not call" external api

service:

```
 @Transactional

 public ProductResponse saveNewProduct(ProductRequest productRequest) {
 try {
 UserResponse user = webClientBuilder.build().get()

.uri("http://user-service/api/user/info/2")
.retrieve()
.bodyToMono(UserResponse.class)
.block();
        ProductEntity productEntity = productMapper.mapFromRequest(productRequest);
        productEntity.setUser(userMapper.mapFromRequest(user));
        ProductEntity save = productJpaRepository.save((productEntity));
        return productMapper.mapFromEntity(save);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(String.format("User with id [%s] does not exist!",     2));
        }
    }
}
```

(the value 2 in path is an example),

wiremock configuration looks like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

   @Testcontainers

   class ProductServiceApplicationTests {

    @Autowired

private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Autowired
private ProductJpaRepository productJpaRepository;

@LocalServerPort
private Integer port;

private WireMockServer wireMockServer;

@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    wireMockServer = new WireMockServer();
    wireMockServer.start();
    WireMock.configureFor("localhost", wireMockServer.port());
}

@AfterEach
public void tearDown() {
    wireMockServer.stop();
}

@Container
private static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:latest")
    .withDatabaseName("testdb")
    .withUsername("testuser")
    .withPassword("testpassword");

@DynamicPropertySource
static void setPostgresProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgresContainer::getJdbcUrl);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgresContainer::getUsername);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgresContainer::getPassword);
}

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    RestAssured.port = port;
}

@Test
void contextLoads() {
}

@Test
void thatShouldAddProductCorrectly() throws JsonProcessingException {
    String jsonResponse = "{ \"id\": 2, \"email\": \"example@email.com\", \"firstname\": \"John\", \"lastname\": \"Doe\", \"products\": [ { \"id\": 1, \"name\": \"example_name\", \"category\": \"example_category\", \"producer\": \"example_producer\", \"price\": 29.99, \"quantity\": 10, \"description\": \"example_description\", \"availability\": true, \"productNumber\": \"ba550199-91a6-4d77-9ef6-8b17d050f517\", \"imageLink\": \"example_image_link\" } ] }";

    ProductRequest productRequestBuilder = ProductRequest.builder()
        .price(new BigDecimal("35.00"))
        .name("test")
        .description("tester")
        .producer("tester")
        .category("test")
        .quantity(5)
        .imageLink("testlink")
        .build();
    stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/api/user/info/2"))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
            .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .withBody("{\"userId\": 2, \"userName\": \"John Doe\"}")));

    Response response = given()
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .body(productRequestBuilder)
        .when()
        .post("/api/product/add")
        .then()
        .assertThat()
        .log()
        .all()
        .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        .extract()
        .response();

    JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(response.getBody().asString());
    Boolean availabilityValue = jsonPath.getBoolean("availability");
    Integer id = jsonPath.getInt("id");
    List<ProductEntity> all = productJpaRepository.findAll();
    Assertions.assertEquals(true, availabilityValue);
    Assertions.assertEquals(1, id);
    Assertions.assertEquals(1, all.size());
}
```

}

It receives the following error:     org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$ServiceUnavailable:   503 Service Unavailable from UNKNOWN
at   org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientRespon  seException.java:336) ~[spring-webflux-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: Error has been observed at   the following site(s):
*__checkpoint ⇢ 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE from GET http://localhost:8082/api/user/info/2 \    [DefaultWebClient]

Please give me guidance or help`